# Docker backup container with startup parameters

Tags: docker, docker-compose, backup, commit

Im facing the same problem since months now and i dont have an adequate solution.

Im running several Containers based on different images. Some of them were started using portainer with some arguments and volumes. Some of them were started using the CLI and docker start with some arguments and parameters.

Now all these settings are stored somewhere. Because if i stop and retart such a container, everything works well again. but, if i do a commit, backup it with tar and load it on a different system and do a docker start, it has lost all of its settings.

The procedure as described here: https://linuxconfig.org/docker-container-backup-and-recovery does not work in my case.

Now im thinking about to write an own web application which will create me some docker compose files based on my setting rather than to just do a docker start with the correct params. This web application should also take care of the volumes (just folders) and do a incremental backup of them with borg to a remote server.

But actually this is only an idea. Is there a way to "extract" a docker compose file of a running containter? So that i can redeploy a container 1:1 to an other server and just have to run docker run mycontainer and it will have the same settings?

Or do i have to write my web app? Or have i missed some page on google and there is already such a solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see the current configuration of a container, you can use:

```
docker container inspect $container_id
```

You can then use those configurations to run your container on another machine. There is no easy import/export of these settings to start another container that I'm aware of.

Most people use a `docker-compose.yml` to define how they want a container run. They also build images with a Dockerfile and transfer them with a registry server rather than a save/load.

The `docker-compose.yml` can be used with `docker-compose` or `docker stack deploy` and allows the configuration of the container to be documented as a configuration file that is tracked in version control, rather than error prone user entered settings. Running containers by hand or starting them with a GUI is useful for a quick test or debugging, but not for reproducibility.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes i already figured out that it is better to use dockerfiles to configure my containers instead of just starting them from the console. Unfortunately i already running some production containers and now try to fix my mistakes.

Comment: If it was easy to fix the mistakes, they wouldn't be considered mistakes. The problem was created by hand and is best corrected by creating the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml by hand rather than a script. Automated tools are equivalent to automated code generators, you don't want to maintain their output.

Comment: So you propose to write own compose scripts for my containers?

Comment: Yes. If you didn't have the time to do it right the first time, hopefully you have time to fix all the mistakes and then do it right the second time.

Comment: Luckily i only run around 10 containers. So the work will be managable. Thank you for your answer. But a really comfortable backupsolution is still not available. Im searching for a one-click snapshot solution for volumes and a one click recovery solution. I think i will have to write such a function by my own.

Answer (score 0):

You would like to backup the instance but the commands you're providing are to backup the image. I'd suggest to update your `Dockerfile` to solve the issue. In case you really want to go down the saving the instance current status, you should use the `docker export` and `docker import` commands.

Reference:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/import/
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/

---

NOTE: the docker export does not export the content of the volumes anyway, I suggest you to should refer to https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I dont have a dockerfile. I also dont have a docker compose file. All what i did is running "docker start ....." If i had a dockerfile or a compose file, i wouldnt have any problems at all since i only had to run the compose file.